# ImportError when using PyInstaller: Cannot import 'get_archive' from 'PyInstaller.utils.cliutils.archive_viewer'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, decompiling

ImportError: cannot import name 'get_archive' from 'PyInstaller.utils.cliutils.archive_viewer' (C:\Users\NEILG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\cliutils\archive_viewer.py)
I have this error is anyone able to fix it.

I have tried everything this won't work pls help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify what you have tried.   What version of pyinstaller did you install?  What is your code like?

Comment: Methinks your issue is https://github.com/serfend/pydumpck/issues/27     Try the workaround.